# Sencha-touch-2.0.0 Horizontal Image list not working in PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, android-emulator, sencha-touch

Has any one implemented the "sencha-touch-2.0.0-commercial\examples\list-horizontal" example in PhoneGap for android OS before. Thanks

Comment: Do any one aware of this issue?

Comment: The Horizontal DataView List is working fine with Chrome Browser, but not working in Android device. Can any one help

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine for me on Android phone and tab. I am using sencha-touch-2.1.0